# Vue.js Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Vue.js and firestore to make a landing page for my project, I've tried to make a registration form to make new account for my website.

I've created a collection in my firebase project, named "users", where the user information where stored when the sign up completed. But when I call the function, the error appeared:

> Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

What can I do? I'll share my code here:

Signup.vue

```
import { Auth, db, usersCollection } from '@/firebase/auth.js'
import * as fb from 'firebase'
import {App} from '@/firebase/app.js'

async addEmail(email,password) {
      var noticeMessage = " Your account has been reserved "
      const {user} = await Auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password )
      await fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      userId: user.uid,
      createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    })
```

auth.js

```
import {App} from './app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';

var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }

export const Auth = App.auth();
export const db = App.firestore();
export const usersCollection = db.collection('users')
```

app.js

```
import Firebase from 'firebase/app'
import credentials from './credentials'


export const App = Firebase.initializeApp(credentials.config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**async-firestore.js**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { isNil } from 'lodash'

let asyncFirestore = null

// Lazy load firestore with async import is important for performance

export default () => {
  if (isNil(asyncFirestore)) {
    asyncFirestore = import(/* webpackChunkName: "chunk-firestore" */ 'firebase/firestore').then(
      () => {
        firebase.firestore().settings({})
        firebase.firestore().enablePersistence({ synchronizeTabs: true })
        return firebase.firestore()
      }
    )
  }
  return asyncFirestore
}
```

**generic-db.js**

```js
import { isNil, keys, cloneDeep } from 'lodash'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

import firestore from './async-firestore'

export default class GenericDB {
  constructor(collectionPath) {
    this.collectionPath = collectionPath
  }

  /**
   * Create a document in the collection
   * @param data
   * @param id
   */
  async create(data, id = null) {
    const collectionRef = (await firestore()).collection(this.collectionPath)
    const serverTimestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

    const dataToCreate = {
      ...data,
      createTimestamp: serverTimestamp,
      updateTimestamp: serverTimestamp
    }

    const createPromise = isNil(id)
      ? // Create doc with generated id
        collectionRef.add(dataToCreate).then(doc => doc.id)
      : // Create doc with custom id
        collectionRef
          .doc(id)
          .set(dataToCreate)
          .then(() => id)

    const docId = await createPromise

    return {
      id: docId,
      ...data,
      createTimestamp: new Date(),
      updateTimestamp: new Date()
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read a document in the collection
   * @param id
   */
  async read(id) {
    const result = await (await firestore())
      .collection(this.collectionPath)
      .doc(id)
      .get()

    const data = result.exists ? result.data() : null

    if (isNil(data)) return null

    this.convertObjectTimestampPropertiesToDate(data)
    return { id, ...data }
  }

  /**
   * Read all documents in the collection following constraints
   * @param constraints
   */
  async readAll(constraints = null) {
    const collectionRef = (await firestore()).collection(this.collectionPath)
    let query = collectionRef

    if (constraints) {
      constraints.forEach(constraint => {
        query = query.where(...constraint)
      })
    }

    const formatResult = result =>
      result.docs.map(ref =>
        this.convertObjectTimestampPropertiesToDate({
          id: ref.id,
          ...ref.data()
        })
      )

    return query.get().then(formatResult)
  }

  /**
   * Update a document in the collection
   * @param data
   */
  async update(data) {
    const { id } = data
    const clonedData = cloneDeep(data)
    delete clonedData.id

    await (await firestore())
      .collection(this.collectionPath)
      .doc(id)
      .update({
        ...clonedData,
        updateTimestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      })

    return id
  }

  /**
   * Delete a document in the collection
   * @param id
   */
  async delete(id) {
    return (await firestore())
      .collection(this.collectionPath)
      .doc(id)
      .delete()
  }

  /**
   * Convert all object Timestamp properties to date
   * @param obj
   */
  convertObjectTimestampPropertiesToDate(obj) {
    const newObj = {}

    keys(obj)
      .filter(prop => obj[prop] instanceof Object)
      .forEach(prop => {
        if (obj[prop] instanceof firebase.firestore.Timestamp) {
          newObj[prop] = obj[prop].toDate()
        } else {
          this.convertObjectTimestampPropertiesToDate(obj[prop])
        }
      })

    return {
      ...obj,
      ...newObj
    }
  }
}
```

**init.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

const config = {
  apiKey: ...,
  authDomain: ...,
  databaseURL: ...,
  projectId: ...,
  storageBucket: ...,
  messagingSenderId: ...,
  appId: ...,
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

**users-db.js**

```
import GenericDB from './generic-db'

export default class UsersDB extends GenericDB {
  constructor() {
    super('users')
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
...
// firebase setup
import './firebase/init'
...
```

You can do firebase auth like this

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
...
      const { user } = await firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password)

      // create a user in firestore `users` table
      const userDb = new UsersDB()
      const newUser = {
        email: form.email,
        name: form.name,
      }
      userDb.create(newUser, user.uid)
...
```

Comment: after your changes, I've this 2 errors : 1) "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined", 2)Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Comment: Okay. I'll add another answer how I handle firebase in vue.